# Why can't I memoize in NextJS' getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using React + NextJS to display a list of products on a category page.

I can get the products just fine using `getServerSideProps`, but I don't like that it re-requests the product list on each visit to the same page. I'm trying to memoize a function that gets the list, and while that *seems* to work (meaning there are no errors thrown), the supposedly memoized function is still called on subsequent visits to the same page.

See the code below, and note that the "get category" console log is shown in the terminal window when I revisit a page, and in Chrome's network tools I see a fetch request made by NextJS.

How can I make it cache the result of my `getCategory` function so it doesn't keep fetching it?

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let config = await import("../../config/config");

  let getCategory = memoize(async (url) => {
     console.log("getting category");
     let response = await axios.get(url);
     if ( response.status ) {
        return response.data;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
  });
  let response = await getCategory(`${config.default.apiEndpoint}&cAction=getCTGY&ctgyCode=${context.params.code}`);

  if ( response ) {
     return {
        props: {
           category: response
        }
     };
  } else {
     return {
        props: {
           category: null
        }
     };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work becuase nextjs api routes are "serverless", which means the state that `memoize` is supposed to remember is destroyed after HTTP call.

The serverless solution is to use a separate service for caching, which is accessible from your api route.

Otherwise, you may need to look at using a custom server.

Comment: Thanks @Triptych, do you know of any examples that outline the solution you mentioned? I'm new to this so an article or two would be really helpful